# Invalid argument(s): Input buffer too short AND Invalid or corrupted pad block

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption, aes

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt chat messages for my app using this code

```
String decrypt(String encrypted, {String key, String iv}) {
  final key = Key.fromUtf8(key); //hardcode combination of 16 character
  final iv = IV.fromUtf8(iv); //hardcode combination of 16 character

  final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.cbc));
  Encrypted enBase64 = Encrypted.from64(encrypted);
  final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(enBase64, iv: iv);
  return decrypted;
}

String encrypt(String value, {String key, String iv}) {
  final key = Key.fromUtf8(key); //hardcode
  final iv = IV.fromUtf8(iv); //hardcode

  final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.cbc));
  final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(value, iv: iv);

  return encrypted.base64;
}
```

I generated a unique 16 characters for key and iv for each chat room u know for security purpose Eg

```
String dec = decrypt("encrypted text" {key: "1204581692165412",  iv: "e16ca718048594ce"});
String enc = encrypt("plain text" {key: "1204581692165412",  iv: "e16ca718048594ce"});
```

But i keep getting the error

```
Invalid argument(s): Invalid or corrupted pad block
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      
PKCS7Padding.padCount   
package:pointycastle/paddings/pkcs7.dart:42
#1      
PaddedBlockCipherImpl.doFinal   
package:pointycastle/padded_block_cipher/padded_block_cipher_impl.dart:112
#2  
PaddedBlockCipherImpl.process   
package:pointycastle/padded_block_cipher/padded_block_cipher_impl.dart:74
#3      
AES.decrypt   
package:encrypt/…/algorithms/aes.dart:63
#4      
Encrypter.decryptBytes   
package:encrypt/src/encrypter.dart:25
#5      
Encrypter.decrypt   
package:encrypt/src/encrypter.dart:31
```

Which successfully encypts but throws the error when decrypting The error is comming from the decrypt function

```
final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(enBase64, iv: iv);
```

So i added padding to be null

`final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.cbc, padding: null));`

I still get another error

```
E/flutter ( 5888): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Input buffer too short
E/flutter ( 5888): #0      CBCBlockCipher._encryptBlock (package:pointycastle/block/modes/cbc.dart:72:7)
E/flutter ( 5888): #1      CBCBlockCipher.processBlock (package:pointycastle/block/modes/cbc.dart:67:13)
E/flutter ( 5888): #2      AES._processBlocks (package:encrypt/src/algorithms/aes.dart:73:25)
E/flutter ( 5888): #3      AES.encrypt (package:encrypt/src/algorithms/aes.dart:41:22)
E/flutter ( 5888): #4      Encrypter.encryptBytes (package:encrypt/src/encrypter.dart:12:19)
E/flutter ( 5888): #5      Encrypter.encrypt (package:encrypt/src/encrypter.dart:20:12)
E/flutter ( 5888): #6      encrypt (package:quelib/src/handlers/helpers/encryption.dart:18:31)
E/flutter ( 5888): #7      _ChatBottomInputState.sendChatData (package:quelib/src/pages/home/chat/chatBtm.dart:293:11)
E/flutter ( 5888): #8      _ChatBottomInputState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:quelib/src/pages/home/chat/chatBtm.dart:244:44)
E/flutter ( 5888): #9      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:989:21)
E/flutter ( 5888): #10     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:198:24)
E/flutter ( 5888): #11     TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:608:11)
E/flutter ( 5888): #12     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:296:5)
E/flutter ( 5888): #13     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:230:7)
E/flutter ( 5888): #14     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:563:9)
E/flutter ( 5888): #15     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:94:12)
E/flutter ( 5888): #16     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:139:9)
E/flutter ( 5888): #17     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:539:8)
E/flutter ( 5888): #18     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:137:18)
E/flutter ( 5888): #19     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:123:7)
E/flutter ( 5888): #20     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:439:19)
E/flutter ( 5888): #21     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:419:22)
E/flutter ( 5888): #22     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:322:11)
E/flutter ( 5888): #23     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:374:7)
E/flutter ( 5888): #24     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:338:5)
E/flutter ( 5888): #25     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:296:7)
E/flutter ( 5888): #26     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:279:7)
E/flutter ( 5888): #27     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1444:13)
E/flutter ( 5888): #28     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
E/flutter ( 5888): #29     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1244:7)
E/flutter ( 5888): #30     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:169:10)
E/flutter ( 5888): #31     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:293:7)
E/flutter ( 5888): #32     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:88:31)
```

Which is coming from encrypt function

```
final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(value, iv: iv);
```

And if i use a particular non-generated dummy key

```
String decrypt(String encrypted) {
  final key =
      Key.fromUtf8("1245714587458888"); //hardcode combination of 16 character
  final iv =
      IV.fromUtf8("e16ce888a20dadb8"); //hardcode combination of 16 character

  final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.cbc));
  Encrypted enBase64 = Encrypted.from64(encrypted);
  final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(enBase64, iv: iv);
  return decrypted;
}

String encrypt(String value) {
  final key = Key.fromUtf8("1245714587458888"); //hardcode
  final iv = IV.fromUtf8("e16ce888a20dadb8"); //hardcode

  final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.cbc));
  final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(value, iv: iv);

  return encrypted.base64;
}
```

It works perfectly without any issue, but this isn't secured. So i want to ask if my problem is from the keys i generated or from somewhere else. Please help me out.

Note: Am using the package `encrypt: ^5.0.1`

UPDATE: Finally fixed
I used the same key value for both IV and Key

Comment: What do you mean by decrypting `"plain text"` in above code?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes oh sorry about that it's decrypting encrypted text

Comment: Alright, but if you are decrypting text then you must first have encrypted it. In principle you can try and decrypt any text, but in that case it must be of the right size *and* unpadding must be turned off - and you would get garbled plaintext in return.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes yes it was able to encrypt but when decrypting the encrypted text is then throws `Invalid argument(s): Input buffer too short`

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Anything?

Comment: No because you don't show an [mcve] so we cannot see where it goes wrong. Obviously your ciphertext is invalid in several ways, but we don't know why.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes ok can you check it now to see if i added what you are looking for?

Comment: The code doesn't even compile (mostly typos or copy/paste issues). And when these bugs are fixed, runtime errors occur (because of invalid test data). Without typos and with valid test data (key, IV, plaintext, ciphertext) the code works on my machine! Probably your data is simply inconsistent, e.g. ciphertext and key do not belong together or similar.

Comment: can you please explaint in more details how did you fix it, I have the same problem now

Comment: @OsamaMohammed I used the same key string for both String key and String iv

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. For it to work for me, you have 2 options, removed the mode setting and let it use the default cic AESMode when setting up the instance of your Encrypter. If you want to use or have to use  cbc mode, you need to set the padding:

```
_encrypter = Encrypter(AES(_key, mode: AESMode.cbc, padding: "PKCS7"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem for so much time and i got solution in chatgpt after a long time below are the changes i did to work properly the main error is the iv should be same during the encryption and decryption of the data i am encrypting and decrypted the mapdata directly with excluding some data

````
final iv = IV.fromLength(16); 

  // Function to generate a unique key for a user based on their UID
  encrypt.Key generateKey(String email) {
    final salt = utf8.encode(email); // Convert UID to bytes
    final hashBytes = sha256.convert(salt).bytes; // Generate SHA-256 hash
    return encrypt.Key(Uint8List.fromList(hashBytes)); // Convert hash bytes to Uint8List and return as the key
  }


 Future<Map<String, dynamic>> encryptData(StringkeySalt,Map<Stringdynamic>data) strong textasync {
    final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(await generateKey(keySalt), mode: AESMode.cbc, padding: "PKCS7"));
    final keysToEncrypt = data.keys.toList();
    final iv = IV.fromSecureRandom(16);

    Map<String, dynamic> encryptedData = {};
    for (var key in keysToEncrypt) {
      final value = data[key];
      if (ExcludeKeys(key)) {
        final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(value, iv: iv);
        encryptedData[key] = base64.encode(iv.bytes) + ":" + encrypted.base64;
      } else {
        encryptedData[key] = value; // Directly store value without encryption
      }
    }
    return encryptedData;
  }

  bool ExcludeKeys(String key) {
    final keysToExclude = ['FCMTOKEN', 'UID'];
    return !keysToExclude.contains(key);
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> decryptData(String keySalt, Map<String, dynamic> encryptedData) async {
    final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(await generateKey(keySalt), mode: AESMode.cbc, padding: "PKCS7"));
    final keysToDecrypt = encryptedData.keys.toList();

    Map<String, dynamic> decryptedData = {};
    for (var key in keysToDecrypt) {
      final encryptedValue = encryptedData[key];
      if (ExcludeKeys(key)) {
        final ivAndEncrypted = encryptedValue.split(":");
        if (ivAndEncrypted.length != 2) {
          print("Error decrypting value for key: $key. Invalid format.");
          continue; // Skip to the next iteration
        }
        final iv = IV.fromBase64(ivAndEncrypted[0]);
        final encrypted = Encrypted.fromBase64(ivAndEncrypted[1]);
        final decryptedValue = encrypter.decrypt(encrypted, iv: iv);
        decryptedData[key] = decryptedValue;
      } else {
        decryptedData[key] = encryptedValue; // Keep value as it is without decryption
      }
    }
    return decryptedData;
  }```
````

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).